# R-Bug? R RODBC sqlFetch returns partial table, sqlQuery returns incorrect results when connection broken silently between RackSpace and Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, r, azure

R users,

I am on a RackSpace running Windows server 2012R2. I intend to use RODBC sqlFetch/sqlQuery to retrieve a table from Azure SQL.

I first created a System DSN, DSNX, using ODBC Data Source Administrator.

I then used RStudio to create a connection:

```
xSQLChannel <- odbcConnect(dsn = 'DSNX', uid = "myuid", pwd = "mypwd")
```

and tried to download the data:

```
xDFABC <- sqlQuery(xSQLChannel, 'select * from dbo.ABC')
```

The function returned silently. However, xDFABC contains only partial data of dbo.ABC - e.g., dbo.ABC contains 22871017, but xDFABC contains 1600 rows only.

And, when I re-run the same code immediately as 2nd attempt,

```
xDFABC <- sqlQuery(xSQLChannel, 'select * from dbo.ABC')
```

It reports an error:

```
 "08S01 0 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Communication link failure" "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'select * from dbo.ABC'"
```

I tried to use `sqlFetch()` to download the full dataset, which itself is a wrap of `sqlQuery()`. Again, first attempt returns a partial datasets with no error message, second attempt returns an error message.

My guess is that the connection is broken when the partial data is downloaded, so it returns the partial dataset without reporting an error. And, when you tried to download again, it reports the error.

The connection issue likely between the RackSpace Server and Azure SQL server, has nothing to do with R. I tried to use Python do the download, fails and report an connection lost errors.

**I am concerned that in R sqlFetch and sqlQuery did not report any error when the download is not retrieved the full datasets as expected.** Should sqlFetch and sqlQuery check the connection is still active after the query, so that we can confident the query runs successful completely?

However, I also tried:

```
count_xDFABC <- sqlQuery(xSQLChannel, 'select count(*) from dbo.ABC')
```

It returns 17000000 at the first time, and 18000000 at the second time, the third time, ..., the tenth time. Never report any error message.

Please let me know whether you experienced similar issue.

Thank you.

yg

Comment: any chance you can give a shot at putting your DB in SQL Azure?  I do this type of work in there all the time with no issues.

Comment: Debugged with Microsoft tech team, it turns out it is a setup issue in Azure SQL. A hack solution is to ask Microsoft to allow this RackSpace machine connects to the Azure VM hosts the data directly, instead of a gateway. - The RackSpace machine is outside of Azure Environment, in default, when connects, it talks to a gateways machine, which in turns talks to the real machine hosts the database. Issues happen when RackSpace and the gateway communicates. R and Python runs on RackSpace can work fine when connect to Azure VM directly.